# Option tag: how to show multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple dropdown that shows and hides a div depending on what is selected.

I would like each selection to reveal two divs (".buzzard" and ".pattern1") but I can't figure out how to tag them both.

Please see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0zpg6d0/3/)

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <select id="opts" data-target=".my-info-1">
    <option value="buzzard" data-show=".buzzard">Buzzard</option>
    ...
  </select>
</div>

<div class="my-info-1">
  <div class="buzzard hide">The buzzard is by far the most common of all our birds of prey, and its expansion has been dramatic</div>
  ...
  <div class="pattern1 hide"><h4>Distribution</h4><img src="#"></div>
  ...
</div>

<script>
$('select#opts').change(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).children().addClass('hide');
  var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
  $(show).removeClass('hide');
});
</script>


.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

I have tried

```
<option value="buzzard" data-show=".buzzard .pattern">Buzzard</option>
```

Comment: Your code is a bit inconsistent (you have both `pattern1` and `pattern`)

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You should use **,**
like `.buzzard,.pattern`

Remember that $ accept a [selector css syntax](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), and white-space minds '**descendant of**' the comma minds '**or**'

Example:

`$('.class1 .class2')` will catch the elements with class2 that it is inside other element with class class1

```
<div class="class1">
    <div>
       <div class="class2">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$('.class1, .class2')` will catch the elements with clases class1 or class2

```
<div class="class1 class2">
</div>
```

The example:
https://jsfiddle.net/L0zpg6d0/4/

Comment: I don't understand the explanation but the comma was just what I needed, thanks.

Comment: @user3821345 thanks, if the reply help to you ,  can you mark the reply as right. Thanks! Also i update the explanation I hope this help you more.